# how to take the hostname or base url

Tags: python, django

How do I get a running base url?

In admin.py, new function/method:

```
def your_api(self, object_id):
        """
        Function save your api
        """
        # print(reverse('admin:index'))
        parameters = Parameter.objects.filter(agregator=object_id)
        concate_endpoint_api = ''
        for parameter in parameters:
            if parameter.flag == 'NO':
                concate_endpoint_api += '{}{}={}'.format(BASE_URL, parameter.keys, parameter.values if parameter.values else 'None')
                concate_endpoint_api += '&'
        return concate_endpoint_api
```

example javascript
windows.location.origin
http://example.com or http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def your_api(self, object_id):
    print(get_current_site(self.request)) 
    # You will get domain name and port of your current site
    return
```

Comment: error

'AgregatorAdmin' object has no attribute 'request'

The function your_api is in the AgregatorAdmin class (admin.ModelAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_actions(self, request):
    self.full_path = request.build_absolute_uri()
    return super(AgregatorAdmin, self).get_actions(request)

def your_api(self, object_id):
    """
    Function save your api
    """
    # print(reverse('admin:index'))
    # print(get_current_site(self.request))
    print(self.full_path)
    parameters = Parameter.objects.filter(agregator=object_id)
    concate_endpoint_api = ''
    for parameter in parameters:
        if parameter.flag == 'NO':
            concate_endpoint_api += '{}={}'.format(parameter.keys, parameter.values if parameter.values else 'None')
            concate_endpoint_api += '&'
    return '{}{}'.format(self.full_path, concate_endpoint_api)
```

solved. thank you friend for the explanation